# Syntax Change - Migrating from JQuery Templates to JsRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

Can anyone help out on how to render a JSRender template after migrating from JQuery Templates?

With the old JQuery Template system I have got the following in my HTML page:

```
        <script id="pageTmpl1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="${theClass1}" style="${theStyle1}">
            <div class="front1">
                <div class="outer1">
                    <div class="content1" style="${theContentStyleFront1}">
                        <div class="inner1">{{html theContentFront1}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back1">
                <div class="outer1">
                    <div class="content1" style="${theContentStyleBack1}">
                        <div class="inner1">{{html theContentBack1}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and then kick it off from a separate js file - excerpt from this file here, with `$( '#pageTmpl1' ).tmpl( pageData ).appendTo( this.$el );` being the key part:

```
        _layout             : function() {

        this._setLayoutSize();

        for( var i = 0; i <= this.pagesCount - 2; ++i ) {

            var $page       = this.$pages.eq( i ),
                pageData    = {
                    theClass1                   : 'page1',
                    theContentFront1            : $page.html(),
                    theContentBack1             : ( i !== this.pagesCount ) ? this.$pages.eq( i + 1 ).html() : '',
                    theStyle1                   : 'z-index: ' + ( this.pagesCount - i ) + ';left: ' + ( this.windowProp.width / 2 ) + 'px;',
                    theContentStyleFront1       : 'width:' + this.windowProp.width + 'px;',
                    theContentStyleBack1        : 'width:' + this.windowProp.width + 'px;'
                };

            if( i === 0 ) {

                pageData.theClass1 += ' cover1';

            }
            else {

                pageData.theContentStyleFront1 += 'left:-' + ( this.windowProp.width / 2 ) + 'px';

                if( i === this.pagesCount - 2 ) {

                    pageData.theClass1 += ' cover-back1';

                }

            }

            $( '#pageTmpl1' ).tmpl( pageData ).appendTo( this.$el );

        }

        this.$pages.remove();
        this.$flipPages     = this.$el.children( 'div.page1' );
        this.flipPagesCount = this.$flipPages.length;

        this._adjustLayout( ( this.state === undefined ) ? this.currentPage : this.state );

    },
```

Does anyone know how I would have to alter the basic setup above in order to migrate to JSRender?

EDIT:

Thanks for your response.

To give some context to my question, here are two examples; the first using jQuery Templates, the second (with advised changes) using JSRender.

1. http://www.timm.ie/example_jqt/
2. http://www.timm.ie/example_jsr/

Though following the indicated syntactical changes, ultimately the desired result is not appearing (in the second case), with no errors to work from.

Changes made were from:

```
        <script id="pageTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="${theClass}" style="${theStyle}">
            <div class="front">
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="content" style="${theContentStyleFront}">
                        <div class="inner">{{html theContentFront}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="content" style="${theContentStyleBack}">
                        <div class="inner">{{html theContentBack}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </script>
```

to:

```
        <script id="pageTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <div class="{{:theClass}}" style="{{:theStyle}}">
            <div class="front">
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="content" style="{{:theContentStyleFront}}">
                        <div class="inner">{{>theContentFront}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="content" style="{{:theContentStyleBack}}">
                        <div class="inner">{{>theContentBack}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

in the index.html, and from:

```
$( '#pageTmpl' ).tmpl( pageData ).appendTo( this.$el );
```

to:

```
$("this.$el").html(
                $("#pageTmpl").render(pageData)
            );
```

in jquery.flips.js.

Any advice you could offer as to why this is would be appreciated.

Comment: $("#pageTmpl").render(pageData) seems to be rendering the correct HTML. Did you mean to write: this.$el.html($("#pageTmpl").render(pageData)); ? $("this.$el") doesn't look right at all...

Comment: You were, of course, right! My bad.

Comment: What I see now is that not all 'pages' of the content come through. You can see an example at [jsrender example](http://www.timm.ie/example_jsr/). Only the last page of content shows, along with the back cover. $flipPages should pick up a total 4 pages of content - the alert on loading indicates that there is only 1 (in comparison with [template example](http://www.timm.ie/example_jqt/)). Do you have any idea as to why this could be?

Comment: I think it is clear the JsRender is working correctly, but you need to figure out your app behavior, and jQuery usage, to fix any remaining bugs/issues. Look at the relationship between the previous behavior with append(), and the new one with html(). You may need to append rather than replace. (The html() method will replace content each time...)

Comment: Incidentally you can leverage JsRender's behavior for rendering your pages as an array - passing in an array to tmpl.render(myArray) will render each item against the template, and concatenate the results. You can also explore using JsViews to use data-binding - see http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/from-render-to-link. JsViews does some cool data-linking (binding) to arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a page using **jQuery Templates**:
[jquery-tmpl/demos/step-by-step/.../0_local-data-source.html](http://borismoore.github.io/jquery-tmpl/demos/step-by-step/0_tmpl-read-only/0_local-data-source.html).

And here is the equivalent page using **jsRender**:
[jsrender/demos/step-by-step/01_inserting-data.html](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/01_inserting-data.html) ([Code here](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/step-by-step/01_inserting-data.html)).

So you see that

**jQuery Templates:**

```
$("#movieTemplate").tmpl(movies).appendTo("#movieList");
```

maps to:

**jsRender**

```
$("#movieList").html(
    $("#movieTemplate").render(movies)
);
```

In fact JsRender does not use the DOM to render.

So you can also write the above as:

```
var html = $("#movieTemplate").render(movies); // Render to string
$("#movieList").html(html); // Insert in DOM
```

Alternatively you can write:

```
var compiledTemplate = $.templates("#movieList"); // Compile template
var html = compiledTemplate.render(movies);  // Render to string
$("#movieList").html(html); // Insert in DOM
```

The string-based rendering is one reason for the [better perf](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/test/perf-compare.html) with JsRender.

As to how the template tags map, here are some of the basic tags:

**jQuery Templates:**

- `${name}`
- `{{html synopsis}}`
- `{{if languages}}...{{else subtitles}}...{{else}}...{{/if}}`
- `{{each languages}}...{{/each}}`

**jsRender**

- `{{:name}}` (See [docs](http://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag))
- `{{>synopsis}}` (See [docs](http://www.jsviews.com/#htmltag))
- `{{if languages}}...{{else subtitles}}...{{else}}...{{/if}}`
  (So no change here: See [docs](http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag))
- `{{for languages}}...{{/for}}` (See [docs](http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag))